# How to attach TransactionScope object with OperationContext.Current object(WCF)

Tags: wcf

We need to create a transactioscope object in our WCF request. We want to add a check that only one object of TransactionScope should be created for a request. So, before creating 'TransactionScope ' object, we want to check if the object is already created or not. If its already created, then we will not create the object. 
For implementing this, we want to attach TransactionScope object with OperationContext.Current so that we can add check before creating any object. Kinldy help/guide us  regarding attaching the 'TransactionScope' object with OperationContext.Current object. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TransactionScopeRequired property of the OperationBehavior attribute: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationbehaviorattribute.transactionscoperequired.aspx

Set it to true to force the creation of a TransactionScope for the operation even if the transaction is not initiated by the client.

Comment: We have to create transaction as follows 
_transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0));

Comment: But to verify if transaction socpe object is already created for the request, we want to attach the transactionScope object with OperationContext.Current(Operation context is implementing Iextensibleobject), So before creating we can check if there is already a TransactionScope object attached with OperationContext.Current then won't create the object otherwise will create the TransactionObject. Kindly guide us that how can we attach TransactionScope object with OperationContext.current object. Thanks

Comment: If you set this attribute to true, there will always be a transaction in the context regardless of whether it came from the client or was created by the WCF infrastructure